# Trying to match regex for mask got issue with min-max length

Tags: regex, validation, max, min, maxlength

hello everyone I'm new to regex and i'm trying to match this mask:
`xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx` so far I've done this

```
^(\d{4}) (\d{4}) (\d{4}) (\d{4})$
```

but how to control min-max length on validation? i need to make it possible to submit 4,8,12 or 16 digits and i can't figure it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You might want to use nested optional groups, or try grouping the part that repeats and use a limiting quantifier with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can go for the following solution:

```
^\d{4}(\h+\d{4}){0,3}$
```

Explanations:

- `\d{4}`exactly 4 digits
- `\h` one horizontal whitespace character
- `(\h+\d{4})` one or more horizontal whitespace char
- `{0,3}` 0 to 3 repetitions of the previous char/block of char
- `^` and `$` are respectively start of line and end of line

Good luck and let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: wow thanks i've tested it on https://regex101.com/ and it matches perfectly but project on which i'm working for is using https://nurulc.github.io/ for masking and when i try to use your regex it fails. but thanks anyway!

Comment: replace the `\h` by a space

Comment: i've replaced \h with \s and it works perfect thanks